# php creating image cant include file?

Tags: php, image, creation

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreate(100, 100);
$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 10,10,10);
imagefill($im, 50, 50, $color);
imagePNG($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

this code works but if I put there require_once

```
require_once('file.php');
```

it doesn't work why?

Comment: Does your require_once making an error ?

Comment: Make sure that file.php is on the same directory as your script file and that it does not print anything else

Comment: required file is in different folder for example: require_once("b/file.php"); but if i require file.php in different file it works, i cant see any error i can see only not loaded image

Comment: Before you use the `header`  function, check if headers have been already send or not: [`header_sent`](http://de.php.net/manual/function.headers-sent.php) - that often is a source of error, you can only set headers if they have not been sent yet.

Comment: if (!headers_sent()) {
header('Content-Type: image/png');
} and it is still writing image can not be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: What do you mean it does not work ??? There must bee and error you can not see the error because  `header('Content-Type: image/png');` is at the head of the script .. add the error you are getting

Comment: "What do you mean it does not work ???" it means image doesnt create, there is not any error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by eliminating any spaces at the end of each line of the included PHP file (like a trim instruction) before CR and LF.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Created a page "file.php" that contain only `phpinfo()` and called it via `require_once('file.php');`.

It looks like your image is not treated as png. It's not rendering or it's destroyed.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30703578)